# Mac OS X: Apache Maven completely unusable

Tags: java, macos, maven

I was trying to install Apache Maven on my Mountain Lion iMac when I found out that Maven is already pre-installed on Mac OS X. I'm really new to development, and I have very little idea what I'm doing with Maven.

I ended up screwing up all of the environment variables, like

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1 [This directory actually doesn't exist at all for me)
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/home
export PATH=$M2:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you can help me out with how I can fix all of the configuration problems I did or how to restore it to factory presets for Mac OS X, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation on Mac is working like that. You have a link under `/usr/share/maven` which is like this:

```
 /usr/share/maven -> /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.1.0
```

So the simplest solution is to change the above link from the above into:

```
/usr/share/maven -> /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.5
```

or

```
/usr/share/maven -> /usr/share/java/apache-maven-2.2.1
```

so you can simply create the installation into:

```
/usr/share/java/apache-maven-2.2.1
```

This can simply solved by a shell scripts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /usr/share/maven
sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/apache-maven-2.2.1 /usr/share/maven
```

which can be named like `maven2` and located into `/usr/local/bin/`.

If you use the link methode you don't need to changed anything in your `PATH` variable.